# How to define content-type with Code Igniter REST_Controller

Tags: json, codeigniter, rest, content-type

I'm working with the REST_Controller extended CI_Controller  and for some reason my requests are all coming back with a content-type of text/html instead of json. In my config, I have json set as the default format:

```
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'json';
```

My results are coming back as JSON, but the content-type isn't being set. Can anyone help with what I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if the config sets the format.  But a simple work around might be just to use the output class to set the header content type, something like:

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

(Taken from the manual: [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html))

Answer (score 0):

While setting contect_type at each functions helps, this can be made generic at controller level by setting this at constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    ...
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
}
```

So you would simply set the output at each function level

```
$this->output->set_output('{"message":"Failure"}');
```

This worked for me.